# Abort a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, generator, list-comprehension

I have a function in python2.7.12 that generates a list from a function f(x) and takes the maximum value like this:

```
max( [f(x) for x in range(n)] )
```

Now I want to abort the generation of the list in case any of its elements is greater than B, and return that element. The result would be the same as doing:

```
v = -float("inf")
for x in range(n):
    v = max( v, f(x) )
    if v > B: return v
return v
```

the problem is the for-loop, while generating less elements, runs slower than the list comprehension for the problem I'm currently working on.
Is there a way to use list comprehension or a simillar generator method, but have it check against B and abort mid-iteration? The objective here is to calculate ONLY the NCESSARY elements, but have it run faster than the first example (where it calculates every element).

Edit:
I have tried many of the tips you guys came up with and settled for the simple implementation of a while-loop. The final code I ended up with is as follows:

```
v = float("-inf")
x = 0
while x < n:
    v = max( v, f(x) )
    if v > B: return v
```

It runs somewhat faster than the for-loop, even though there may be a faster solution (still didn't time all of the proposed solutions, sorry), but I like the simplicity.

Thank you.

Comment: You can add an if statement in the list comprehension.

Comment: @JackTheCrab that would still calculate them

Comment: why not just a `while` statement ?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: because then you can't get that *one value* that breaks the test.

Comment: Basically, you can't do much better than a `for` loop. The loop can move to a generator function, so you can limit the use of the `max()` function to only one call, and that's it. The generator function overhead may make this not worth while.

Comment: How much slower is the for-loop? And how far does it typically get until it finds a value above B?

Comment: In your example you don't use the list, just the max element, do you actually need the list as well in the real use case?

Comment: @Andris No, I don't need to keep the list, but I need to know: is there any element greater than B? -> yes, return the first found -> no, return the maximum value.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I just finished implementing a while loop and it is indeed a little bit faster than the for-loop. The other generator methods also result in similar times. The problem in question is the minimax algorithm for the Berkeley pacman AI project. I am updating the code on the OP to the final version I'm using. Thanks everyone for the help!
average time per decision using for: 0.0823 s
average time per decision using while: 0.0505 s

Answer (score 1):

So here is a generator that generates values from its first argument until a value is over its second:

```
def generate_until_threshold(iterator, threshold):
    for value in iterator:
        yield value
        if value > threshold:
            return
```

Then this works:

```
max(generate_until_threshold((f(x) for x in range(n)), B), -float('inf'))
```

But it will not run as fast as the list comprehension.

Comment: why B? what if the max value generated by `f(x) for x in range(n)` is smaller than B?

Comment: Then the if statement is always false, and it just loops over the whole thing.

Comment: The default would be `float('-inf')`; it only applies if there are no values in the input.

Comment: And this is basically the same thing as the OP had (a `for` loop), but using a generator this time rather than `return`. But you call `max()` only once.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, exactly. So it goes.

Answer (score -2):

Try like this:

```
>>> [x**2 for x in range(10)]
```

[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]

```
[x**2 for x in range(10) if x < 7]
```

[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]

EDIT: Checked with [f(x) for x in range(10) if f(x) < 7] - and it calls function f(x) twice, so it's even slower

Comment: It still calculates the rest of the values and checks against the expression. While the result yields the same answer, the calculation time and what not is more than it should